# c# textbox autocomplete order

Tags: c#, winforms, autocomplete, textbox

I'm working on winforms, I'm using a textbox with autocomplete.
Is there any way to change the order of the autocomplete results? 
(In my case I want the order descending, I tried to add Order desc in the `AutoCompleteStringCollection` query but it's not working)

This is a part of my code:

```
string CaseNumQuery = "select TSK_CaseNum from VW_Tasks Where Year(TSK_CallDate)=" + DateTime.Now.Year + " order by TSK_CaseNum desc";
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(DBServices.cnString);
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(CaseNumQuery, conn);
conn.Open();
SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
AutoCompleteStringCollection CaseNumCollection = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
while (reader.Read())
{
    CaseNumCollection.Add(reader[0].ToString());
}
textBox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource = CaseNumCollection;
reader.Close();
reader.Dispose();
reader = null;
cmd.Dispose();
cmd = null;
```

Comment: Please show us what you have tried

Comment: ok I added a part of my code, please can you take a look

Comment: By default the results are sorted in descending order (highest to lowest value). If there are ties, then the Updated field is used (most recent appears first). Are your results are not in descending order?

Comment: When I start typing in the textbox1, the suggestappend is giving me the suggestion in a ascending order, how can I make it descending?